# postgresql 9.6 using all my ram

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have 16G ram in my server. I assigned the next memory parameters:

```
effective_cache_size = 10GB
work_mem = 128MB
maintenance_work_mem = 4GB
shared_buffers = 4000MB
```

My server is only dedicated to postgresql. When I run a procedure that preforms a big select I see the postgresql uses all the memory on the server  and that is my status:

```
[/PostgreSQL/] : free -m
                         total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
           Mem:          15883         291         158        4109       15433       11112
           Swap:          3815         106        3709
```

Is it normal? This may influence on complicated selects that I run with joins?

Comment: I guess it's keeping as much data as possible in RAM for caching purposes.

Comment: Where does it use "all" memory? `available = 11112` means there are still 11GB of your 16GB available.

Comment: You're confusing kernel fs cache usage with "usage". The kernel grabs all spare memory and caches everything it can from the file system, but the second anything asks for more memory, the kernel dumps some of the cache and hands over that memory to the requesting process. This is completely normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading it wrong.

The value for buff/cache indicates that ram is used to cache, but it is free for applications if needed.

Take a look here for a detailed explanation: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: Right. Free ram is wasted RAM. You want the system using as much RAM as possible at all times.